# ruby - How to make an array of arrays of letters (a-z) of varying lengths with maximum length five

Tags: arrays, ruby, permutation

So I'm trying to make an array of all possible permutations of the alphabet letters (all lowercase), in which the letters can repeat and vary in length from 1 to 5. So for example these are some possibilities that would be in the array:

```
['this','is','some','examp','le']
```

I tried this, and it gets all the variations of words 5 letters long, but I don't know how to find varying length.

```
("a".."z").to_a.repeated_permutation(5).map(&:join)
```

**EDIT:**

I'm trying to do this in order to crack a SHA1 encrypted string:

```
require 'digest'
def decrypt_string(hash)
  ("a".."z").to_a.repeated_permutation(5).map(&:join).find {|elem| Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(elem) == hash}
end
```

Hash being the SHA1 encryption of the word, such as `'e6fb06210fafc02fd7479ddbed2d042cc3a5155e'`

Comment: Just do the same for lengths 1, 2, 3 & 5? Note that the 5 will likely take a looooooong time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your method slightly.

```
require 'digest'

def decrypt_string(hash)
  arr = ("a".."z").to_a
  (1..5).each do |n|
    arr.repeated_permutation(n) do |a|
      s = a.join
      return s if Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(s) == hash
    end
  end
end
```

```
word = "cat"
hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(word)
  #=> "9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50"
decrypt_string(hash)
  #=> "cat"
```

```
word = "zebra"
hash = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(word)
  #=> "38aa53de31c04bcfae9163cc23b7963ed9cf90f7"
decrypt_string(hash)
  #=> "zebra"
```

Calculations for `"cat"` took well under one second on my 2020 Macbook Pro; those for `"zebra"` took about 15 seconds.

Note that `join` should be applied within `repeated_permutation`'s block, as `repeated_permutation(n).map(&:join)` would create a temporary array having as many as `26**5 #=> 11,881,376` elements (for `n = 5`).

Comment: Nice use of `repeated_permutation`'s block form. Seems `"zzzzz"` (which would be the last element) takes about 30 +/- 2 seconds (for me) which isn't too bad given the brute force nature. That being said I would still go with a rainbow table instead if the OP is going to be performing this operation multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind the possibility of repeating strings then

```
e = Enumerator.new do |y| 
  r = ('a'..'z').to_a * 5
  loop do 
    y << r.shuffle.take(rand(4)+1).join
  end
end
```

Should work. Then you can call as

```
e.take(10) 
#=> ["bz", "tnld", "jv", "s", "ngrm", "phiy", "ar", "zq", "ajjn", "cn"]
```

This:

- Creates an `Array` of a through z repeated 5 times
- Continually shuffles said `Array`
- Then takes the first 1 to 5 ("random number") elements from the shuffled `Array` and joins them together

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying before you answered, this way works (with some modification), but it takes really long, is there a way to shorten it?

Comment: @SamP this would be inefficient for your updated intention; however your proposed solution of generating an Array of more than 12.35M strings is also going to yield slow results. Bruce force cracking is a time consuming procedure in general. We could possibly make this more efficient by implementing a set and checking if the yielded value already exists in the Set. That being said you are still looking for a needle in a pile of needles and that could take a long time (could be rhe first guess or the 12,350,223rd guess)...

Comment: ...best bet is generate a [rainbow table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and use that as your source. Generate every possible combination and it's SHA1 encryption as a reference then it just becomes a look up table. Generation will take time up front but store this in a file (better yet a database) and your results will be extremely fast.